# Table taking out table lock on Delete using PrimaryKey value. It may be index corruption how can I fix this?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2017, I have a table that has been working trouble free for years.

I started getting random database lock-ups which appear to be due to a table lock being taken out on one particular table.

I used a lock report which identified 7 locks on this SQL:

`DELETE FROM WasteSchedule WHERE WasteScheduleId=@P`

The Delete is being instigated from PHP8 using a parameterised SQL statement.
`WasteScheduleId` is the Primary Key.

[image]

I believe that Table level locking should not take place unless 5000 rows are affected. In some cases this can be lower, but in this case I only have 9k rows on the whole table and I am using a single primary key value to delete a single row.

I checked the indexes; one for the primary key and another for a foreign key.

I tried to `Rebuild` the primary key index and got the following error:

```
===================================

One or more errors occurred. For details click hyperlink associated with error message. 
(SqlManagerUI)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.IndexRebuild.OnRunNow(Object sender)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.PanelExecutionHandler.Run(RunType runType, Object sender)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.DoPreProcessExecutionAndRunViews(RunType runType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.ExecuteForSql(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.IExecutionAwareSqlControlCollection.PreProcessExecution(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.RunNow(RunType runType, Object sender)
```

I tried to `rebuild` the foreign key index and got the same error.

I then tried to delete the foreign key index and got another error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Drop failed for Index 'WasteOrderHeader_FK'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=16.100.47021.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Drop+Index&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

Lock request time out period exceeded. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1222)

For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-1222-database-engine-error

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

It looks like I have corrupt Indexes but at this stage I usure what is the best sequence of action to resolve this issue.

EDIT: The reason that this has become an issue is that the lock on the delete is just sitting there and not releasing; causing all sorts of issues with the application using it.

Comment: How have you jumped from error message "Lock request time out period exceeded" to "It looks like I have corrupt Indexes"?

Comment: Don't use the silly GUI for this kind of stuff, because it looks like it masked the real errors. I very much doubt your index is corrupt. Check the query plan instead of guessing, does it actually use index seek, or do you see whole SCAN.

Comment: @MartinSmith, it says so in the error message, but i doubt it's actually true

Comment: The error message is "Lock request time out period exceeded" - this would indicate another open transaction probably. The error message doesn't say anything about corruption

Comment: So I have other questions - is locking on a 10k row table really taking so much time that its an issue?   Or are we just learning how the things work?

Comment: Where is the data that says a table lock was taken out anyway? What kind of lock? It is normal for intent locks or schema stability locks to be taken out. At the moment all we know is that you ran some "lock report" and possibly misinterpreted the results

Comment: I did an edit on the question. I have an issue on the PHP application where the use of this table causes the lock to be taken out and not released. As you can imagine this is causing all sorts of issues with the application using it.

Comment: If the lock is not released then this means the connection is being left open with a non committed transaction. Even if it is a row lock this can cause blocking. And will certainly block things like your attempted rebuild

Comment: Sounds like an application is not cleaning up its connection properly. Make sure you use `try` `finally` to closed the connection in case of error, and always use `SET XACT_ABORT ON;`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a transaction error.
I found the offending process with this:

```
SELECT
    session_id,
    blocking_session_id,
    text,wait_time,
    total_elapsed_time
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_requests
CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) 
WHERE 
    session_id IN 
    (
        SELECT
            blocking_session_id
        FROM 
            sys.dm_exec_requests
        WHERE
            (DB_NAME(database_id) = 'MyDatabase') AND
            (blocking_session_id <> 0)
    )
```

and it threw up a view that was causing the lock. I looked at it and it uses an
`INNER JOIN` on another table. On a 'hunch' I discovered some of the joined records were missing.

It appears that these orphaned records have been causing the issue.

I am using PHP8.0 to query the view and, if the view has the joined record missing, it hangs the process.

This does, however, leave an issue outstanding: Why under this very specific set of circumstances is a view with a duff `INNER JOIN` record causing the transaction to remain open?

Never seen this sort of thing before. SQLSRV Driver issue?